# Determine whether $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine whether $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$U = \{(r, s, t) \mid r, s, \text{ and }t \in \mathbb{R}, −r + 3s + 2t = 0\}.$$

I have never seen such a question how would i prove this?

Comment: Hint: Prove that it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and that it's a subspace (Closed under addition and scalar multiplication)

Comment: When is your homework due? Do you have other subjects too?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace if

1. $\vec{0} \in V$
2. $V$ is closed under addition and constant multiplication; i.e. if $\vec{v},\vec{w} \in V$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $a\vec{v} + b \vec{w} \in V$.

Can you prove both?

**UPDATE**

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{v}, \vec{w} \in U$. Then there exist $s,t,S,T \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 2s+2t \\ s \\ t \end{pmatrix}\\
\vec{w} = \begin{pmatrix} 2S+2T \\ S \\ T \end{pmatrix}
$$
So let $\vec{u} = a\vec{v} + b\vec{w}$. Can you find the correct values for $s,t$ to show $\vec{u} \in U$ as well?

Comment: How exactly would you prove 2?

Comment: @Micky see update

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
-r+3s+2t=0
$$
is a plane, so it's a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

First, prove that (0,0,0) is an solution to the equation:

−r+3s+2t=0

-0+3.0+2.0=0

0=0 (true)

And than, prove that if (a,b,c) and (d,e,f) are solutions to the equation, m.(a,b,c) + n.(d,e,f) must to be a solution too (m and n real numbers):

(a,b,c) is a solution, so:

−r+3s+2t=0

-a+3b+2c=0 (i)

(d,e,f) is a solution, so:

−r+3s+2t=0

-d+3e+2f=0 (ii)

Well, note that if (i) and (ii) are true (and they are), (iii) and (iv) will be too:

-a+3b+2c=0 (i)

m.(-a+3b+2c)=m.0

m.(-a+3b+2c)=0 (iii)

and:

-d+3e+2f=0 (ii)

n.(-d+3e+2f)=n.0 (ii)

n.(-d+3e+2f)=0(iv)

Finally, (iii)+(iv) is true too:

m.(-a+3b+2c)=0 (iii)

+

n.(-d+3e+2f)=0(iv)

=

m.(-a+3b+2c) + n.(-d+3e+2f)=0+0 (iii)+(iv)

m.(-a+3b+2c) + n.(-d+3e+2f)=0 (iii)+(iv)

So, m.(a,b,c) + n.(d,e,f) is a solution too!

Comment: Welcome to the site. We generally try not to solve the homework problems for people completely without them doing something to complete it...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know it. Tks

Comment: No problem, I upvoted your answer. It will do you good to typeset your answers in MathJax, they are much easier to read then. You can learn to do this here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference